# Parse Google Referral Location with PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to parse a Referral URL from Google but there are no keywords in the URL. Is this something new with google? Is there a way to tell what they searched so I can log the keywords used?

URL I am having issues with:

`http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=13&ved=0CEMQFjAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stubwire.com%2Fvenue%2Flightsofthesouth%2Fgrovetown%2F1527%2F&ei=QNPAUPHEDJCo8ASp1oH4Cg&usg=AFQjCNGS5KrvXDib-RmEIv2A8UDyWfkXBw&rct=j`

URL I can parse:

`http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=fitzgerald's%20%22service%20fee%22&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stubwire.com%2Fevent%2Felectricsixtba%2Ffitzgeralds%2Fhouston%2F4255%2F%3Freferral%3DAPI-fitzlivemusic.co&ei=IdfAUJzHJ-Od2QW_koHgBA&usg=AFQjCNHfHPCvTsskRe1KVwgrbOa-ccO0YQ`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a new policy by Google. Check this article by SeoMoz for more details: http://www.seomoz.org/blog/google-hides-search-referral-data-with-new-ssl-implementation-emergency-whiteboard-friday

Google recommends that you use their [Webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) to analyse search queries.

Comment: Thanks for the video of the answer. So I am guessing that there is also not any API if you have the webmaster tools to figure this out?

Comment: It seems that there is API - https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/docs/2.0/developers_guide

Comment: I took a look at the link you posted and while it does have an API, what I was hoping to find is when someone comes to my site that I can tell what keyword they came from so I could customize their content and log the keyword they used. This helps when new clients sign up so I know how that user found us.

Comment: I understand, sadly Google is actively blocking such behaviour/tracking. Maybe you can use some sort of funnel inside Google Analytics in connection with their adwords tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Keywords are no longer available on the query string if the user is logged in in Google.

[Accessing search query data for your sites](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/10/accessing-search-query-data-for-your.html)